# Django Operation error: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')

Tags: python, django

I can not start my django server after running a statement through manage.py for generating class diagrams from db.
And I always get this error but I don't know how to deal with it.
OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')

I have tried re-install all the modules relevant to mysql for django but it was useless.

Comment: It is very urgent! Really need you guys help

Comment: Can we see the line that errors?

Comment: I am not sure whether the error was caused by my local mysql settings and I also tried to reinstall mysql yesterday but it didn't work either. So I used a remote server to run my application. But it was really weird that it didn't have such error today when running locally...Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default RSA files are not generated.

Try this:

```
shell> bin/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup
```

Comment: Keep running at this solution but am not sure how to execute this command as there is no DB instance terminal available on azure

Answer (score 0):

Paste below lines in setting (**init.py**)file

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```