# SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed

Tags: mysql, azure

Am trying to deploy a Django based web application on Azure.

I deployed the application using Github method and it's deployed properly. Now I created a Mysql `Azure Database for MySQL` over there. It's up and running, I even added the IP address to enable it to connect it. I am able to connect it through MySQL workbench as well.

But the problem is that when am trying to connect the application to database, it gives me `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')` error. I tried `disabling` the SSL connection on mysql through the portal as well, it doesnt make any difference.

I tried adding official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-configure-ssl) too. Changed my db connecting parameter to

```
   DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<name>',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pass>',
        'HOST': '<host>',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'ssl': {
                'ssl-ca': '/path/on/local/machine/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'} #I change the path when deploying on server
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not able to connect.

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077344/3538065) answer 2-3 times, but it also requires me to ssh into instance and then run the command, which I just cant do while it's there on azure.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, you should look at the version mismatch.

In my case below are the working versions which I figured out by hit and trial.

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.13
mysqlclient==1.3.14
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
```